# Start Sonar server inside eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

can I start a sonar server inside from eclipse?
Or do I always have to execute the startserver.bat?

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `startserver.bat`, to start the server.

You can have look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090355/how-to-run-a-batch-script-bat-file-from-eclipse) if you want to call the bat file from eclipse.