# Unable to find startserver.bat file of sonar plugin of eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I've seen below URL

- [Start Sonar server inside eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542252/start-sonar-server-inside-eclipse)

to start the sonar server.But I am not able to find startserver.bat file.I have installed sonar as a plugin in eclipse by go to eclipse marketplace.

Comment: You need to [download and install](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar) a sonar server first. The plugin is not a sonar installation, it is just a tool that helps to interact with the sonar server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sonar dashboard is designed to updated from a build running on a project's automated build server. Build servers normally work against code taken from a project's shared development branch.

The Eclipse plugin, on the other hand, is designed to run against the code located in the Eclipse workspace, which may or may not have been committed.

Two different usecases, the Eclipse plugin is used to test the effects of code fixes on the reported Sonar violations. Obviously when those fixes are committed, this will eventually update the Sonar dashboard.

Comment: I have download the sonar server and also configure it.Server is running perfectly.But , when I associate sonar server with my project in eclipse , it gives an error "project 'cdl' with key 'cdl:cdl' not found on server"

My project name is 'cdl' and groupId and artifactID is also 'cdl' in pom.xml.
And cdl is also name of project in eclipse.
Please help me.

Comment: Thanks stackoverflow members for your help.
I have analysed my project using sonar statically. Now I want to analyse my project dynamically , I mean while my project is executing. 
My project's module taking so much of memory and time also.So , is there any way to track memory and time while project is running?

Comment: That is really another question. Dynamic analysis in Sonar normally refers to code coverage and unit test metrics. This will tell you what percentage of your code is not executed and how long each test takes. Memory utilisation is not a metric which is captured. It's an interesting one.