# How to open BAT (windows batch) file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, batch-file

How to open BAT (windows batch) file in Eclipse? When I am doing `Open File...` the file runs, not opens. How to open it in editor?

Dragging file on Eclipse also runs it.

Comment: right-click - open with - Text Editor See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090355/how-to-run-a-batch-script-bat-file-from-eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this plugin:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/shelled/

And also I think you chould  go to preferences->general -> editors->file associoations and add bat to the list

Answer (score 10):

The ShellEd plugin doesn't seem to be for Windows BAT files--only Linux/Unix shell languages.

Going to Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations is how to have Eclipse open BAT files in a text editor, though.

Comment: I've set Eclipse to open `.bat` files in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) by that same dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Theres is a new open source plugin called [Batch-Editor](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/batch-editor) available on eclipse market place. It has syntax color support for dark and white theme included and has an outline view + quick outline for labels.

Here an example screenshot:
[image: Batch-Editor example screenshote (dark theme].

It supports also echo and escaping:
[image: Batch-Editor example screenshot (echo handlig white theme)]

**PS: I am the author of the mentioned plugin.**