# Running a Batch file in Eclipse populates an unknown directory

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, minecraft

I'm trying to run a batch file in Eclipse (with the end goal of making it into a Run As Configuration), but when I double click the batch file in Eclipse, instead of populating the correct directory with files (that are specified in the batch files), it populates the place I installed Eclipse in. Now, this is all well and good, but eclipse has a default folder named plugins, and the batch file also needs to use a folder named plugins. I cannot rename either folder, as both programs will break. I wonder if there is a way to make batch files run in their default location, instead of transporting them to some other directory.

Comment: I do not know if I understood your question, but maybe you only have to create a _External Tool Configuration_ and specify the _Working Directory_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1090379/6505250

Comment: @howlger This worked for me. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an ***[External Tools Configuration](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-antexttools.htm)*** and specify the working directory:

1. ***Run > External Tools > External Tools Configuration...***
2. Select the *Program* node and click the ***New launch configuration*** button
3. Enter the location of your **batch file** in the field ***Location***
4. **Specify** the working directory in the field ***Working Directory***
5. Click ***Run*** to save the configuration and execute it

To **rerun** your batch file click the **[image: Launch external tool] button** in the main toolbar.

To edit the batch file (and change the double-click behavior for this file) right-click the batch file and choose *Open With > Text Editor*.