# Eclipse Plugin for ClearCase

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Installed on my Windows 7 (32-bit) computer is ClearCase Explorer 8.0.1.9 and Eclipse Java IDE 4.7.2 (Oxygen) and JDK 1.8.0_161.

I am looking for suitable plugin so that I can perform check-out / check-in to ClearCase from Eclipse workbench.

I found a plugin on sourceforge but I would prefer something from IBM.

Also I cannot use the newer product ClearTeam Explorer, I must use ClearCase Explorer.

Comment: Why you prefer something from IBM? Why can you not use the newer product? Would a ClearCase Git bridge also be an option for you?

Comment: @howlger Prefer IBM because of the support. Ask my boss why can't use newer product. What is ClearCase Git bridge?

Comment: The idea of a ClearCase Git bridge is to access ClearCase via Git like a Git repository (similar to the [SVN Git bridge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion)). But I have no experience with this. I used ClearCase 10 years ago. At that time I preferred the SourceForge Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: @howlger Closed network. No Internet access. Looks like Git Bridge is a no-go. I understand that sourceforge plug-in is adequate?

Comment: Eclipse is not an IBM tool

Comment: @Elyahu ClearCase is an IBM product and IBM have provided Eclipse plugins for earlier versions of ClearCase.

Comment: @Abra A Git bridge does not require internet access but since it is software not from IBM, you need permission to install it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using cleartool command line options to checkout or checkin.
it is very simple and got clean response.

Do integrate batch commands with Eclipse

Check this related Question [How to run a batch script (.bat file) from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090355/how-to-run-a-batch-script-bat-file-from-eclipse)

IBM Help page for Clear case commands
[Cleartool subcommands for base ClearCase and UCM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ctintro.htm)

Comment: If you want to see the history of the currently opened file, compare it with another version to take over some parts of it, it will get complicated. But if that's not a requirement (and it wasn't asked for), you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to update your clearcase client to 9.0.0.6/9.0.1.2 or later to use the cte plugins that support that release of eclipse. 8.0.1.x tops out at 4.6.

The plugin mentioned by @Elyahu is last updated in 2013, and may not work with a current eclipse/jvm release.

Comment: I assume `cte` stands for `Clear Team Explorer`. If it does, then I did mention that I am not able to use that product.

Answer (score 0):

As I remarked, in any case Eclipse is not an IBM tool, so you can find any suitable plugin you find on the net.

That one is an IBM one, but for lower ClearCase versions, but it might be OK, since its only a plugin, and you only need a check-out <-> check-in ability

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24025674

Enjoy,
Eli

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you have 'ClearCase Explorer 8.0.1.9 ', I assume that you have installed it in your computer/VM/asset.
During installation of Clearcase, there is option you can select to install 'CTEUpdateSite'. If you enable that option, you will see /CTEUpdateSite directory. You can configure it in your eclipse Help--> Install Software, Add a 'Local' location so that those plugins will get installed. Post Installation you will able to do all ClearCase operations from Eclipse IDE itself.

Comment: Two and a half years after posting this question, we are no longer using Eclipse Oxygen nor ClearCase 8. Also, we are in the process of replacing ClearCase with Git.